# Why is JSFiddle using ligatures, and is this breaking my code?

Tags: jsfiddle

After posting some code on JSFiddle, I noticed that there appeared to be an errant space in my code.  Upon trying to correct it I discovered that the problem is with rendering, not with what I entered, and saw that every instance of a lowercase `f` followed by a lowercase `i` resulted in a ligature connecting them.  This would be fine if they weren't doing it ***to code***.  Less importantly: what is going on here, and what is causing this?  More importantly: could this be the cause of my code not running?

[The fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/7sr6fmxq/1/).

[image: JSFiddle with ligatures]

Comment: I'm not seeing this. And I'm pretty certain the ligature is the result of the font being used for output. Try setting the font-family via the CSS to confirm.

Comment: Oh, whoops. Now I see what you are getting at. But it is still due to your browser's default font sets, I'm sure. When I view the fiddle, the monospaced (code) areas are rendered with DejaVu Mono and `fi` appear as two distinct characters.

Comment: Rats. I'm still a bit wrong. Looking at the developer console in Chrome, it looks like the selected css rule for the font-family is : `font-family
'Fira Mono', Monaco, 'Andale Mono', 'Lucida Console', 'Bitstream Vera Sans Mono', 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;`  AGAIN, still not causing the issue you are seeing when I view that fiddle, so likely due to one of the above fonts in your local environment doing this.